# AWS API Gateway security

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am playing around with Amazon Gateway API and am struggling to get my head around security.

Obviosuly the API I create cannot be accessed by anyone and needs to be secured. Amazon suggest using API keys or IAM roles. I have a few questions:

1. How can i authenticate my client requests so that my app and only my app can make use of the API?
2. How does AWS determine a role for an incoming request?
3. If I choose API key approach, how does it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon API Gateway security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746750/amazon-api-gateway-security)

Comment: Please edit your first question with the extra details instead of creating new questions with more details.

Comment: my bad. Are you able to hep me on those points above? very stuck!

Answer (score 1):

> How can i authenticate my client requests so that my app and only my app can make use of the API?

If your backend is a Lambda function, you can grant permission to API Gateway to access it.

If your backend is a HTTP backend, you will have to find out the authenticate strategy at your HTTP backend side.

> How does AWS determine a role for an incoming request?

If your API is required IAM auth, the incoming request has been signed with AWS sigV4 algorithm. AWS is able to determine the permission of the credential is used to sign the request.

> If I choose API key approach, how does it work?

All the incoming requests have to contain the API key in the header. If the key is allowed to access the API, the request will be processed, otherwise it will return 403.

Comment: so I will be using Lambda and some of the function will return sensitive data so I want to be able to stop anyone from sending the HTTP request and obtaining the data.

Comment: You can use the IAM auth or Custom auth feature to secure your API to allow only authenticated user be able to obtain the data from your Lambda function. 

Here is the documentation for Custom auth: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html